# Failure/Error: get :show, id: @user.id, format: :json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test this controller but an error is returning.

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end

end

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) { request.headers['Accept'] = "application/vnd.marketplace.v1" }

  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryBot.create :user
      get :show, :id => @user.id, format: :json
    end

    it "returns the information about a reporter on a hash" do
      user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
      expect(user_response[:email]).to eql @user.email
    end

    it { should respond_with 200 }
  end
end
```

bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb

Failures:

1) Api::V1::UsersController GET #show returns the information about a reporter on a hash
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user.id, format: :json

```
 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: id
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) Api::V1::UsersController GET #show 
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user.id, format: :json

```
 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: id
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 0.05594 seconds (files took 2.35 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:12 # Api::V1::UsersController GET #show returns the information about a reporter on a hash
rspec ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:17 # Api::V1::UsersController GET #show

Comment: Controller specs are deprecated, FYI. You should switch to using request specs for new tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing a `params` hash containing the parameters you're interested in submitting:

```
get :show, params: { id: @user.id }
```

Comment: Thank for this tip, however the problem only switch for

Failure/Error: respond_with User.find(params[:id])
     
     Devise::MissingWarden:
       Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
       Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.

Comment: I don't understand how to use requet specs for tests. I'm new and are using this tutorial that use some deprecated gems, http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book
So Im trying use updated gems and then bugs are inevitable.